# How to fix XMLHttpRequest error while loading XML feed form a different domain using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I need to load an xml feed from vimeo, for this I am using jquery like this:

```
$(function(){

// Get vimeo feed
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://vimeo.com/api/v2/<my username>/videos.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function( xml ) {
        $(xml).find( "video" ).each( function() {
            console.log( $(this).find( "title" ) );
        });
    }
});

});
```

But I get this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://vimeo.com/api/v2//videos.xml. Origin http://localhost:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I am using MAMP if that makes any difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [vimeo API - User](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/simple-api#user)

> Making the URL
>
> http://vimeo.com/api/v2/username/request.output
>   **username** Either the shortcut URL or ID of the user, an email address will NOT work.
>   **request** The data you want. The different request types are listed below.
>   **output** Specify the output type. We currently offer JSON, PHP and XML formats.

So instead of making a request like <strike>http://vimeo.com/api/v2//videos.xml</strike> make a request like http://vimeo.com/api/v2//videos.json

Now you can use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to get the results like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "http://vimeo.com/api/v2/{username}/videos.json?callback=?";
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, datum) {
            items.push("<ul>");
            items.push("<li>Title: " + datum.title + "</li>");
            items.push("<li>Tags: " + datum.tags + "</li>");
            items.push("</ul>");
        });
        $("#result").html(items.join(""));
    });
});
```

View Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/Ssdjp/1/

Comment: thanks a lot for the code snippet works like a charm, I was just reading about the JSON bits